# How do I fix a broken regsvr32 that crashes?

Tags: regsvr32

I dont know what happend but I cant register any dlls anymore. It seems like regsvr32 or some dependent dll:s have been broken (I dont think its a virus-thing, but of course you can never know).

I regulary register dlls to communicate with different hardware and today I dont have the time to make a cleen install of my computer. So, do you know any way to repair the regsvr32 and dependent dlls?

Its not really a programming question, but very related, because regsvr32 is a big part of my programming day.

The errors I got are (translated from swedish error message):
title:regsvr32.exe - Cold not find a component
message:This program could not be started because of PSAPI.DLL could not be found.

And if clicked ok on that I got a new error:
title:regsvr32.exe - Cold not find a component
message:This program could not be started because of OLEACC.DLL could not be found.

in the windows32-folder I got PSAPI.dll, 23kB, changed 2008-04-14 and OLEACC.dll, 160kB changed 2004-08-04.
regsvr32.exe, 30kB, changed 1996-08-09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I just expanded the regsvr32.ex_ found in the I386-folder on the installation disk.

expand regsvr32.ex_ regsvr32.exe

And copied the expanded file to the system32-folder, and now it works again.

Comment: btw, it might be worth doing a CHKDSK against your boot drive in case you have some corruption due to disk failure.